# Why sql give not right sum in result?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Rows in table `Balance`:

[image]

Row `Amount` have type decimal 10,1

We are make select:

```
SELECT
                u.UserID as UserID,

                (ifnull(b.BalanceDebit,0) - ifnull(bc.BalanceCredit, 0)) as Balance,
                ifnull(bc.BalanceCredit, 0) as BalanceCredit

            FROM 
                Users as u
            LEFT JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            UserID,
                            SUM(Amount) as BalanceDebit
                        FROM
                            Balance
                        WHERE 
                            Operation='debit' AND StatusPay = 'success'
                        GROUP BY 
                            UserID
                    ) as b ON u.UserID = u.UserID
            LEFT JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            UserID, 
                            SUM(Amount) as BalanceCredit
                        FROM
                            Balance
                        WHERE 
                            Operation='credit' AND StatusPay = 'success'
                        GROUP BY 
                            UserID
                    ) as bc ON bc.UserID = u.UserID

            WHERE 
                u.UserID != '12'
```

After select, in result we are see next rows:

[image]

But result balance not right. Result show that all users have 10.0 on balance, but only one user (UsersID = 40) have 10.0.

Tell me please where error in sql quesry? How right select sum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your first LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
ON u.UserID = u.UserID
```

should be

```
ON u.UserID = b.UserID
```

Also, if you are trying to find the balance, I think you would take all of the credits, and subtract all the debits. So instead of this:

```
ifnull(b.BalanceDebit,0) - ifnull(bc.BalanceCredit, 0)
```

Shouldn't it be this?

```
ifnull(b.BalanceCredit,0) - ifnull(bc.BalanceDebit, 0)
```

Comment: oh sorry and thanks)) `ifnull(b.BalanceDebit,0) - ifnull(bc.BalanceCredit, 0)` - this not need edit. balance = debit - credit;

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the subqueries, the same result can be achieved like this:

```
SELECT
    u.UserID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.operation = 'debit' THEN b.operation ELSE 0 END) balance_debit,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.operation = 'credit' THEN b.operation ELSE 0 END) balance_credit,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.operation = 'debit' THEN b.operation ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.operation = 'credit' THEN b.operation ELSE 0 END) balance
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
    balance b
    ON u.UserID = b.UserID AND b.StatusPay = 'success'
WHERE u.UserID <> 12
GROUP BY u.USERID
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Left Joins can be combined into one using CASE (and fix the bad join condition):

```
SELECT
    u.UserID AS UserID,

    (ifnull(b.BalanceDebit,0) - ifnull(b.BalanceCredit, 0)) AS Balance,
    ifnull(b.BalanceCredit, 0) AS BalanceCredit

FROM 
    Users AS u
LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                UserID,
                SUM(CASE WHEN Operation='debit' AND StatusPay = 'success' THEN Amount end) AS BalanceDebit,
                SUM(CASE WHEN Operation='credit' AND StatusPay = 'success' THEN Amount end) AS BalanceCredit
            FROM
                Balance
            WHERE 
                (Operation='debit' AND StatusPay = 'success')
              OR
                (Operation='credit' AND StatusPay = 'success')
            GROUP BY 
                UserID
        ) AS b ON b.UserID = u.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN condition pointed out by Bill Gregg was the main cause of your results being off. The query can be rewritten to avoid having to JOIN to Balance twice though:

```
SELECT u.UserID
, COALESCE(b.CalculatedBalance, 0)
, COALESCE(b.BalanceCredit, 0)
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT UserID,
    SUM(CASE Operation
      WHEN 'debit' THEN Amount*-1
      WHEN 'credit' THEN Amount
    END) AS CalculatedBalance,
    SUM(CASE Operation
      WHEN 'credit' THEN Amount
    END) AS BalanceCredit
  FROM Balance
  WHERE StatusPay  = 'success'
  GROUP BY UserID
  ) AS b
ON u.UserID = b.UserID
WHERE u.UserID != '12'
```